# Is there a way to check if multiple statements are true using a single 'elif'?

Tags: python, performance, if-statement, python-3.5

In response to [this challenge](https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/challenge-the-classic-fizzbuzz-challenge/82165), I wrote the following code:

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print("Fizz")
    if i % 5 == 0:
        print("Buzz")
    if i % 15 == 0:
        print("Fizzbuzz")
    elif i % 3 !=0:
        print(i)
    elif i % 5 !=0:
        print(i)
    elif i % 15 !=0:
        print(i)
```

It works, but I'm not sure it is the most efficient method. For example, one of the things I was unsure of is how to include several tests for divisibility using just 1 `elif`. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I don't think this does work. This will print "FizzBuzz" twice for multiples of 15.

Comment: What you've written doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most efficient way for any number:

```
def fizzbuzz(n):
    output = ''
    if n % 3 == 0:
        ''.join(output, 'Fizz')
    if n % 5 == 0:
        ''.join(output, 'Buzz')
    return output if output else str(n)

print "\n".join(fizzbuzz(n) for n in xrange(1, 21))
```

Comment: Your first if could just be 'n % 15'.  Single comparison instead of two for the same result.  You could also remove a comparison by keeping a return string and joining 'Fizz' for 3 and 'Buzz' for 5.  If they're both true, you return 'FizzBuzz'.  No need to check for 15.

Comment: Request an edit for the answer, if you can format it correctly I'd be happy to add you as a collaborator. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing:

```
elif i % 3 !=0:
    print(i)
elif i % 5 !=0:
    print(i)
elif i % 15 !=0:
    print(i)
```

You can do

```
elif i % 3 !=0 or i % 5 != 0 or i % 15 != 0:
    print(i)
```

Comment: How so? I don't understand why.

Comment: If a number is divisible by 15 it is necessarily divisible by 3 *and* 5.

Comment: I answered his question. I didn't question his logic on solving the problem. It might not be correct, that isn't my concern. He asked for help to shorten the program, and that I gave him.

Comment: But is there a way of eliminating the 3 and 5 statements if it is 15?

Comment: @ShawnLi First check for divisibility by 15, only then check 3 and 5.

Comment: At the top of your program, check `if(i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0)` then print out FizzBuzz and `continue` the loop.